# Creating SSO enabled AccountUser via API

Tags: api

I'm creating AccountUsers using the SFMC API, however I'm not able to configure the SSO settings. I'm trying to add the following block to the SOAP create request. It should be feasible, as it is described in the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssoidentity.html).

What am I missing here?

```
<SsoIdentities>
   <Ssoidentity>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
       <FederatedID>TST</FederatedID>
   </Ssoidentity>
</SsoIdentities>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SOAP body instead:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{TOKEN}}</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
<CreateRequest xmlns=“http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI”>
         <Objects xsi:type=“AccountUser”>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil=“true”/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil=“true”/>
            <Client>
               <ID>*******</ID>
            </Client>
            <UserID>******</UserID>
            <Password>******</Password>
            <Name>******</Name>
            <Email>******</Email>
            <NotificationEmailAddress>******</NotificationEmailAddress>
            <ActiveFlag>true</ActiveFlag>
            <IsAPIUser>true</IsAPIUser>
             <DefaultBusinessUnit>******</DefaultBusinessUnit>
            <IsLocked>false</IsLocked>
            <MustChangePassword>false</MustChangePassword>
            <SsoIdentities>
               <SsoIdentity>
                  <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                  <FederatedID>******</FederatedID>
               </SsoIdentity>
            </SsoIdentities>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Swetha - I don't see any difference with what I posted originally. This only creates the user but for some reason the <SsoIdentities> tag is ignored.